# How to target both JVM/Native and Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm stuck trying to write code shared by server (Kotlin native/JVM) and client (Android)

I have both Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA.
I want to be able to write Kotlin code that can be used from my Android project and also used independently (either JVM or Native, not sure yet). IntelliJ has lots of nice multiplatform option on project setup but I can't build them from Android studio.

Kotlin shared project has this plugin

`plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.11'
 }`

And builds fine - i.e. I can run it from IntelliJ and all is well.

But how do I import this into Android studio. I've made the following changes

settings.gradle

`include ':app', ':shared'
project(':shared').projectDir = new File('../../kotlin/shared')`

It's clearly attempting to build from the right files, but gradle sync fails immediately with the message:

> Plugin [id: 'kotlin-multiplatform', version: '1.3.11'] was not found
>   in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/standard_plugins.html for
>     available core plugins)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'kotlin-multiplatform:kotlin-multiplatform.gradle.plugin:1.3.11')
>     Searched in the following repositories:
>     Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I assuemd this would be repository issue, but both projects (shared lib, and Android project) only have mavenCentral.

So I'm baffled. How do I build the same code for both Android and JVM/Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong plugin ID in your Gradle build. Try

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.21'
}
```

instead.

iOS and Android application tutorial look related https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html

You may check the MPP library tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/multiplatform-library.html

Please find the documentation for the Kotlin MPP plugin here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#publishing-a-multiplatform-library

Comment: That easy. Thanks you!